# Avoid creation of browser action in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I am creating a chrome extension. When the extension is added to chrome, then icon next to address bar is added also (browser action). My extension does not need any browser action. So, how can I avoid creation of this icon?

Edit: My manifest file:

```
{
"background": {
  "persistent": true,
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
},

"description": "This extension ...",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Something",
"permissions": [ "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/*", 
"https://*/*" ],
"version": "1",

"icons": {
"128": "msdos.png"
}
```

Comment: This is how chrome battles malware extensions installed by nonsavvy users. There's nothing you can do to avoid it. You can add an icon and a title via browser_action key though to make your extension look pretty at least.

Answer (score -1):

If your browser extension does not need `browser_action`, you can simply remove it from your `manifest.json` see: from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.
It will remove the icon next to the bar address.

More details about `manifest.json`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest

If it does not work, do you mind to post your `manifest.json`

EDIT: As wOxxOm mentionned, [since January 2016](https://blog.google/products/chrome/new-year-new-chrome/), Chrome shows all the icons of the web extension. So there is no way to hide it (except on the older version of Chrome).

Comment: Your answer is applicable to old versions of chrome or some chromium forks only. The new Google Chrome always adds an icon for an extension.

Comment: I added my manifest.